# Exhaustive Enumeration to find Cube Root (Python)

Tags: python, root, cube

```
#Find the cube root of a perfect cube
x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
ans = 0
while ans**3 < abs(x):
    ans = ans + 1
if ans**3 != abs(x):
    print x, 'is not a perfect cube'
else:
    if x < 0:
        ans = -ans
    print 'Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans)
```

When I run the code, it prints "Enter an integer: ".
Then input a number (for example 125), but nothing happens.
I enter "print ans", but it says *ans* is not defined.

I've been learning Python for 4 hours.
I hope I'm just missing some obvious step.

Comment: When i run your code its working perfectly, which version of python you are using ?

Comment: Can't reproduce; this seems to run fine. It sounds like you typed this into interactive mode or something; you may have done something wrong there.

Comment: I suggest, you accept your own answer to indicate that the problem has been solved. And why do you learn Python 2 instead of 3? [It will not be supported in the near future.](https://pythonclock.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the problem was that I was in **interactive mode**.
Having just started yesterday, I didn't even know the difference.
Thanks for the quick responses guys.